# Triple Fault While Enabling Higher Half Kernel

Tags: assembly, linker, x86, paging, osdev

I get a triple fault when i try to enable Higher Half Kernel in my OS. Basically this is my linker.ld:

```
/* The bootloader will look at this image and start execution at the symbol
   designated as the entry point. */
ENTRY(loader)

SECTIONS {
   /* The kernel will live at 3GB + 1MB in the virtual
      address space, which will be mapped to 1MB in the
      physical address space. */
   . = 0xC0100000;

   .text ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000) {
       *(.multiboot)
       *(.text)
       *(.rodata*)
   }

   .data ALIGN (0x1000) : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000) {
        start_ctors = .;
        KEEP(*( .init_array ));
        KEEP(*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY( .init_array.* )));
        end_ctors = .;
        *(.data)
   }

   .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000) {
       _sbss = .;
       *(COMMON)
       *(.bss)
       _ebss = .;
   }
}
```

boot.asm:

```
    ;Global MultiBoot Kernel Recongnzation
MAGIC equ 0x1badb002
FLAGS equ (1<<0 | 1<<1)
CHECKSUM equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)


;Putting in object file
section .multiboot
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM




section .data

KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE equ 0xC0000000                  ; 3GB
KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER equ (KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE >> 22)  ; Page directory index of kernel's 4MB PTE.

align 0x1000
BootPageDirectory:
    ; This page directory entry identity-maps the first 4MB of the 32-bit physical address space.
    ; All bits are clear except the following:
    ; bit 7: PS The kernel page is 4MB.
    ; bit 1: RW The kernel page is read/write.
    ; bit 0: P  The kernel page is present.
    ; This entry must be here -- otherwise the kernel will crash immediately after paging is
    ; enabled because it can't fetch the next instruction! It's ok to unmap this page later.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0                 ; Pages before kernel space.
    ; This page directory entry defines a 4MB page containing the kernel.
    dd 0x00000083
    times (1024 - KERNEL_PAGE_NUMBER - 1) dd 0  ; Pages after the kernel image.


section .text
    extern kernelMain
    extern callConstructors
    extern page_directory
    extern pages_init
    ; reserve initial kernel stack space -- that's 16k.
    STACKSIZE equ 0x4000
    ; setting up entry point for linker
    loader equ (_loader - 0xC0000000)
    global loader

        _loader:
                ;Enable Paging START

                    ; NOTE: Until paging is set up, the code must be position-independent and use physical
                    ; addresses, not virtual ones!
                    mov ecx, (BootPageDirectory - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE)
                    mov cr3, ecx                                        ; Load Page Directory Base Register.

                    mov ecx, cr4
                    or ecx, 0x00000010                          ; Set PSE bit in CR4 to enable 4MB pages.
                    mov cr4, ecx

                    mov ecx, cr0
                    or ecx, 0x80000000                          ; Set PG bit in CR0 to enable paging.
                    mov cr0, ecx


                    lea ecx, [higherhalf]
                    jmp ecx

        higherhalf:
                ; Unmap the identity-mapped first 4MB of physical address space. It should not be needed
                ; anymore.
                mov dword [BootPageDirectory], 0
                invlpg [0]

                mov esp, stack           ; set up the stack
                call callConstructors

                push eax
                push ebx
                call kernelMain

        _eof:
             cli
             hlt 
             jmp _eof


section .bss
align 32
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE      ; reserve 16k stack on a uint64_t boundary
```

I tried debugging it and i get this in my qemu.log(cut down to last part of log, where check_exceptions occur):

```
Trace 0x7f99594ba2c0 [001023ed] 
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xe
     0: v=0e e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:001023f9 pc=001023f9 SP=0010:00006f08 CR2=001023f9
EAX=00106000 EBX=80000011 ECX=001023e0 EDX=003ff003
ESI=00000000 EDI=00111000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00006f08
EIP=001023f9 EFL=00000086 [--S--P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000cb268 00000027
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=80000011 CR2=001023f9 CR3=00106000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=000003ff CCD=80000011 CCO=LOGICL  
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0xe new 0xd
     1: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:001023f9 pc=001023f9 SP=0010:00006f08 env->regs[R_EAX]=00106000
EAX=00106000 EBX=80000011 ECX=001023e0 EDX=003ff003
ESI=00000000 EDI=00111000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00006f08
EIP=001023f9 EFL=00000086 [--S--P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9a00 DPL=0 CS32 [-R-]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000cb268 00000027
IDT=     00000000 000003ff
CR0=80000011 CR2=001023f9 CR3=00106000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=000003ff CCD=80000011 CCO=LOGICL  
EFER=0000000000000000
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xd
Triple fault
```

If you want to see my full source code, to investigate this problem more here it is: https://github.com/amanuel2/OS_Mirror . Here is where i got the tutorial from: http://wiki.osdev.org/Higher_Half_x86_Bare_Bones .  Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using GDB as debugger and remote debugging your kernel. You could compile with debug information, and then use GDB to step through your code to find where it fails?

Comment: You sure you QEMU supports PSE? The CR4 values in the dump are all 0.

Comment: Found the solution... Its because i forgot to change ViedoRam to 0xC0b008  .. basically my kernelMain